# How Do You Pass A View Input Argument To @State Variable?

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, arguments

I have a basic SwiftUI question - I have a view that takes argument, in my case "symbolName" for which I would like to fetch prices. I have a class function that does this, but **passing the view argument to the FetchPrice as an argument does not work**. When I use a fixed string, such as "GE", it works. I am sure there is a right way to do this, thanks for any hints and tips!

Error:

> Cannot use instance member 'symbolNameV' within property initializer;
> property initializers run before 'self' is available

```
import SwiftUI

struct SymbolRow2: View {
    var symbolNameV: String

    @ObservedObject var fetchPrice = FetchPrice(symbolName:symbolNameV)

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> property initializers run before 'self' is available

By calling

```
FetchPrice(symbolName: symbolNameV)
```

you're accessing `self`. The code above is actually:

```
FetchPrice(symbolName: self.symbolNameV)
```

To solve this you can create a custom `init`:

```
struct SymbolRow2: View {
    private var symbolNameV: String
    @ObservedObject private var fetchPrice: FetchPrice
    
    init(symbolNameV: String) {
        self.symbolNameV = symbolNameV
        self.fetchPrice = FetchPrice(symbolName: symbolNameV)
    }

    ...
}
```